# calling chrome.tts.speak function for any length of text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, text-to-speech

I have text of length nearly `11000` . when i pass that text to `chrome.tts.speak` function, it is not speaking the content. Later, after doing some debugging i found that if i send text of `500` length  , it speaks normally. So, i did this

```
for(var start = 0; utterance.length > 500 ; start++){
   text = utterance.substring(0,500);
   chrome.tts.speak(text);
    // console.log(text)
   utterance = utterance.substring(500,utterance.length);
}
```

now the problem is that it doesn't wait for this function `chrome.tts.speak(text);` to complete.

**All i want to give `chrome.tts` engine to any length of text and it should speak it.**

how can i ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tts).  It points out that successive calls to `speak` interrupt previous calls unless you use the `enqueue` option.  That should get you where you want.

Edit: From the documentation, an example of the `enqueue` option:

```
chrome.tts.speak('Speak this next, when the first sentence is done.', {'enqueue': true});
```

Edit: Applying it to your code

```
chrome.tts.speak(text, {'enqueue': true});
```

Comment: thanks for that. I tried using this object but it doesn't work. If possible, please create the text of 10k length and pass it to this function in such a way that it will speak it.

Comment: Updated, but if you've tried something like that, it would be very helpful to include that as part of your question, showing the code. ;)

Comment: Another side-effect of your algo is that you'll be breaking words into pieces by splitting at exactly every 500 characters.  Perhaps find the first space before the 500th character and split there.

Comment: thanks for that, the above code is not the actual code. i will improve it .